# R eval list strings for data.frames and then concat the data.frames

Tags: r, list, eval, dataframe

I have the following situation where Im pretty desperate.

```
paste("crossdata","$geno$'",1:4,"'$data",sep="")
```

generates 4 strings which look like that:

```
"crossdata$geno$'1'$data" "crossdata$geno$'2'$data" "crossdata$geno$'3'$data" "crossdata$geno$'4'$data"
```

I want to retrieve the corresponding data.frames of these 4 strings via evaluation of one of these strings and the combine them via cbind. However when Im doing something like this:

```
cbind(sapply(parse(text=paste("crossdata","$geno$'",i,"'$data",sep="")),eval))
```

that does not work. Can anybody help me out? 
Thanks

Comment: `library(fortunes); fortune(106)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datlist <- list(adat=data.frame(u=1:5,v=6:10),bdat=data.frame(x=11:15,y=16:20))

extdat <- c("datlist$adat","datlist$bdat")

do.call('cbind',lapply(extdat,function(i) eval(parse(text=i))))

  u  v  x  y
1 1  6 11 16
2 2  7 12 17
3 3  8 13 18
4 4  9 14 19
5 5 10 15 20
```

Of course this uses `eval` + `parse`, which usually means you are on the wrong track.

Comment: Wow thats eactly what I needed. Thank you so much. Hmm and in the end it wasnt that hard. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using the combination of `parse` and `eval` is like saying that you know how to get from New York City to Boston and therefore making all your travel plans by going from your origin to New York, then to Boston, then to your desitination.  In some cases this may not be to bad, but it is a bit of a long detour if you are traveling from London to Paris.

You should first learn the relationship and difference between subsetting lists using `$` and `[[` (see `?'[['` for the documentation) and when it is, and more importantly, is not appropriate to use `$`.  Once you understand that you should be able to find solutions that do not require `parse` and `eval`.

Your problem may be as simple as (untested since your example is not reproducible):

```
do.call( cbind, lapply( 1:4, function(x) crossdata[['geno']][[x]][['data']] ) )
```

or possibly

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(as.character(1:4), function(x) crossdata$geno[[x]]$data ) )
```